# On Gatsby CMS how can i set the about page as a index page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

Hi I installed the gatsby cms starter with netlify, this project came with a started template called kaldi that have a basic post and pages, is easy to create fields and build the grapql data, but Im confuse the way that the route works, for example I can`t found the way to put the abot page as a index page

this the index page that came ith the data info from the post fields

```html
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'

export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props
    const { edges: posts } = data.allMarkdownRemark

    return (
      <Layout>
        <section className="section">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="content">
              <h1 className="has-text-weight-bold is-size-2">Latest Stories</h1>
            </div>
            {posts
              .map(({ node: post }) => (
                <div
                  className="content"
                  style={{ border: '1px solid #eaecee', padding: '2em 4em' }}
                  key={post.id}
                >
                  <p>
                    <Link className="has-text-primary" to={post.fields.slug}>
                      {post.frontmatter.title}
                    </Link>
                    <span> &bull; </span>
                    <small>{post.frontmatter.date}</small>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    {post.excerpt}
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <Link className="button is-small" to={post.fields.slug}>
                      Keep Reading →
                    </Link>
                  </p>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        </section>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

IndexPage.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    allMarkdownRemark: PropTypes.shape({
      edges: PropTypes.array,
    }),
  }),
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] },
      filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "blog-post" } }}
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 400)
          id
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            templateKey
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

I changed the filter to refer the about-page ans this bring me all the data form about fields, but in the netlify content manager is no showing the preview page

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby, by default, will generate a path based on the file name. So if you have a file at `pages/index.js` it will generate a file named `public/index.html` which is typically going to be served as the root directory index.

To change this page, you have a few options.

1. Configure your server to serve `public/about.html` as the root directory index, though this is uncommon and likely to be hard to debug later.
2. Replace `pages/index.js` with the content of your `pages/about.js` file.
3. Export the top-level component from `pages/about.js` from `pages/index.js` as the default

Comment: If the about page was being generated programmatically using a page template and a graphQL query, then I wouldn't be able to just export the page template into index.js, correct? Then the only option would be for me to set the server to serve the programmatically created page as the root directory index.

Comment: @user2030942 All you need to do is change the path you pass to `createPage` in gatsby-node.js. E.g. `createPage({ path: "/index/", component: "./src/templates/anything.jsx" })`

Comment: My createPage function looks as follows: allWordpressPage.edges.forEach(edge => {
        if (edge.node.status === 'publish') {
            createPage({
                path: edge.node.slug,
                component: slash(pageTemplate),
                context: {
                    id: edge.node.id,
                    parent: edge.node.wordpress_parent,
                    wpId: edge.node.wordpress_id,
                }
            })
        }
    });

Comment: Are you suggesting that I call createPage again after the first call to create the /index/ path, passing in the id of the homepage?

Comment: @user2030942 No I'm saying that if you want the slug `about` to be `index` you can just override it. If you have a different question you should open a separate question though.

Comment: I did. Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868720/how-can-i-set-the-index-page-of-my-gatsby-site-to-be-one-of-the-dynamically-gene