# How can I set the index page of my Gatsby site to be one of the dynamically generated pages?

Tags: javascript, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api

I have a Gatsby site that queries information from a Wordpress REST API with GraphQL to dynamically create the site pages. I'd like to set my index page to be the homepage that is being created dynamically i.e `home.html`

I saw this post that was similar
[On Gatsby CMS how can i set the about page as a index page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592681/on-gatsby-cms-how-can-i-set-the-about-page-as-a-index-page)

However, they have an `about.js` file that corresponds to their about page, meaning they can export it as a component and use it in index or they can even just copy the contents of that file over to `index.js`. The homepage that I want to set as my index is being generated dynamically and using a GraphQL query that can't be used outside of the `page.js` template. So I don't see an easy way to copy that over to another file.

I guess my last option would be to set my server to point to the static file in `public/home.html` and serve that as the site root, but the person in that posting tries to deter people from doing that.

Any ideas?

Here is page.js template that generates the pages of the site:

```
const PageTemplate = ({ data }) => (
    <Layout>
        {<h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.currentPage.title }} />}
        {
           renderBlocks(gatherBlocks(data.currentPage.acf.page_blocks, data))
        }
    </Layout>
);

export default PageTemplate;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query ($id: String!) {
        currentPage: wordpressPage(id: {eq: $id}) {
            title
            id
            parent {
                id
            }
            template
            acf {
                page_blocks {
                block_type {
                    acf_fc_layout
                    cs_title
                    cs_text
                }
                wordpress_id
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

And here is my index page:

```
import React from "react"

import Layout from "../components/global/Layout"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the Tank Gatsby site.</p>
    <p>Now go build something great.</p>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: How are you currently fetching the data for the page you want as the homepage from Wordpress in `gatsby-node.js`?

Answer (score 8):

I experienced the same situation today. I used the following approach to use my dynamically created page with uri '/home'(fetched from wordpress using GraphQL query) as the home page of my Gatsby site:

1. Delete the default index.js file in your pages directory.
2. In gatsby-node.js file, change the uri
   of page from '/home' to '/' just before using the CreatePage API.
   Here is the sample code to achieve the desired result:

```js
// loop through WordPress pages and create a Gatsby page for each one
  pages.forEach(page => {
    if(page.uri==='/home/')
      page.uri = '/'
    actions.createPage({
      path: page.uri,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/${page.template.templateName}.js`),
      context: {
        id: page.id,
      },
    })
  })
```

In the above code, pages refer to the pages fetched from WordPress using GraphQL.

Comment: This is perfect. I am using the slug "index" :+1:

Answer (score 3):

I could not find an easy way to create *index* page programmatically. Made it work nonetheless, details below.

- `createRedirect` is valid approach but might affect *SEO* and definitely [affects E2E tests](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/6800) cause actual page content gets rendered with a small delay.
- Another thing to consider is that having *pages/index.js* file is **required** in order to get *index.html* file generated on production build. This gets in the way of using `createPage({ path: '/', ...` cause in my case programmatically created *index* page was overwritten by the static one (made of *pages/index.js*). This looks like a bug to me (or rather not supported feature). Corresponding [github issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/21843).
- [looks like](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11173) `deletePage` and `createPage` gatsby-node APIs work asynchronously, hence we have to `delete` index page created from static file and `create` the one we want in the same callback. *Not 100% sure about this one, but that's my observation.*
- `onCreatePage` API is a good candidate since it gets called upon original *index* page creation and we can take that one out and replace it with the custom one, programmatically created.
- There is a catch however - `CreatePageArgs` interface (unlike `CreatePagesArgs`) doesn't provide reference to `graphql`, hence fetching data might be tricky.

**Final solution:**

```
export function onCreatePage(args: CreatePageArgs): void {
  const { page } = args;

  if (page.path === '/') {
    const { deletePage, createPage } = args.actions;

    const indexPageComponentPath = path.resolve(
      './src/pages/index.tsx',
    );

    deletePage({
      path: '/',
      component: indexPageComponentPath,
    });

    createPage({
      path: '/',
      component: yourComponentPath,
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution: use [`createRedirect`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/actions/#createRedirect) in `gatsby-node.js`.
E.g.:

> index.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
export default () => <></>
```

> gatsby-node.js

```
...

exports.createPages = async ({ actions }) => {
  const { createRedirect } = actions

  createRedirect({
    fromPath: '/',
    toPath: '/home',
    isPermanent: true,
    redirectInBrowser: true,
 })
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to address this by copying the contents of the `page.js` template into `index.js` , but instead of using a regular GraphQL query, which cannot be used outside of the page template, I used [`useStaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/) instead and hardcoded the id of the index page I was retrieving data from.